# Nag Panchami and its importance?

Tags: shiva, worship, history

There are a few questions in my mind regarding **Nag Panchami**:

- What is the history and importance of Nag Panchami?
- Why do we worship *Nagas* or *Snakes* in Nag Panchami though we're afraid of them?
- Why do many people draw *Nagas* or *Snakes* on a paper and stick it to their walls on this occasion?
- What's the importance of *Meethi Seviyan* (a sweet) during this day? 

  [image]

Comment: [related, not duplicate] [Why do Hindus feed milk to snake?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/577/93)

Comment: too many questions...kindly consider having only one or 2 questions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The story of **Naga Panchami** is described in [Chapter 24 of Varaha Purana](http://hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/the-varaha-purana/vol-i/chapter-24/topic-1).

The Progeny of Ananta, Vasuki, Kambala, Karkotaka, Padma, Maha Padma, Sanka and Kulika filled the earth and they were crooked, heinous and violent and with their fangs they stung people and reduced them to ashes. This used to reduce human population and virtuous men went to abode of Lord Brahma and asked him for a solution. Then Brahma cursed the serpents as follows.

> Brahma said to Serpents,
>
> - Since you are annihilating my progeny, the men, in another age, in the Swayambhu Manvantara, by curse of the mother, you will face a
>     serious decline.
>
> Serpents said,
>
> - O God. We were made crooked by nature by you. Our Venom, cruelty, and the use of eye as weapon were all given by you. The intensity of
>     all that was given may be reduced.
> - O God. Please allot us separate regions.
>
> Brahma said,
>
> - Patala, Vitala, Sutala are the regions allotted to you. You may all have your abode there.
> - I ordain that you shall enjoy all pleasures till seventh Manvantara.
> - At the beginning of Vaivasta Manvantara you will become relations of Devas as well as of Garuda.
> - Then all your progeny will be consumed by fire but for your own selves there will be no danger
> - The end of such serpents as are fierce and insolent will certainly occur, but not of others. You may eat and bite person if he is
>     destined, but also to retaliate when somebody injures you.

The serpents thereafter went to nether world allotted to them. All this happened on **Panchama tithi**. So, this tithi is auspicious and capable of removing all sins.

**If one remains austere on that day, give us all that is sour in food and bathes the images of Nagas in milk, they become friendly towards him.**

Comment: Varaha Purana presents snakes in a negative picture. Snakes earlier were very good, much better than humans. They helped everyone, it was humans who killed most of them. Humans deserved curse for their sinful act and not snakes.

Comment: I really liked the way you've described the answer :-)

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria  That was their Dharma. Brahma created them like that. It was **Karma** of humans to die in their hands. Which Purana mentions them as good? But Snakes are favorite to Lord Shiva.

Comment: @RishiKulshreshtha I just copied from Varaha Purana.

Comment: @AnilKumar Read "Apprenticed to a Himalayan Master" by Sri M. Brahma never created them like that. Famous sage Patanjali was none other than a snake.

Comment: @AnilKumar Similar to Patanjali, there were many good snakes and by many, I mean very large number.

Comment: Panchami tithi can repeat several times in an year. Is the specific tithi actually mentioned in the Varaha Purana? The other deleted answer says: "falls on the fifth day of the moonlit fortnight of the month of Sravana, which falls in the month of July or August."