# Pouring of Milk on Naga

Tags: belief, rituals

In some Brahmin Sects there exists practice of pouring milk on Naga statues on Thai and Aadi Fridays. Has it been mentioned in any puranas?What is the significance ?  Why it is not applicable to all Brahmin sects?

Comment: Related not duplicate [Nag Panchami and its importance?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2542/3500)

Comment: Every Friday I see these instances pouring milk on naga. Tha too in Tamil  months AAdi and Thai  all the Fridays milk will be poured and offering betel leaves banana etc. It is not related to naga panchami.

Comment: Yes.It's not related to Naga Panchami but Milk is poured during Naga Panchami and i want to just link these questions.So, posted as comment.