# How to celebrate Naag panchmi?

Tags: puranas, naga

[Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10489/8696) is the reason why we celebrate Naag panchmi. The answerer although embedded the way to celebrate the same very swiftly as -

> If one remains austere on that day, give us all that is sour in food and bathes the images of Nagas in milk, they become friendly towards him.

I am interested to be informed the complete ritual to follow on the day. Can anyone impart from a valid source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chapter 114 (pg 28)](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/12976/4/Chapter2_1425-1504p.pdf) of the **Narada Purana Vol 4** gives an account on the vratas observed on Panchami tithis. It describes a ritual performed on the Shukla Panchami of Sravana.

> **27-29. This rite (in propitiation of serpents) is performed on the fifth day in the bright half of the month of Sravana,** by men firm in
>   their belief in the Vedas.
>
> **On either side of the door-way, figures of poisonous serpents should be drawn in cowdung. He should worship them with scents, etc.**
>
> Thereafter he should worship Indrani with gold, silver, etc, curds,
>   raw rice-grains, water from Kusa grass, scents, fragrant flowers,
>   incense, lights and hoards of Naivedyas. After circumambulating and
>   bowing down, he should pray with great devotion. He should give the
>   articles of worship to leading Brāhmaņas.
>
> 30.“In all my births, may these gold, silver, etc. that have been given to Brahmanas be productive of endless benefit."
>
> 31.O Narada, he who gifts away along with this utterance, the articles with great devotion, will delight Kubera, the presiding deity of
>   wealth, who bestows affluence like gold, upon his devotees.
>
> 32.After observing the holy rite, the man should feed Brahmanas with devotion. Thereafter, he should partake of his food surrounded by his
>   wife, children and friends.
>
> **33-34a. The devotee should propitiate serpents with milk on the fifth day in the dark half of the month of Bhadrapada, (thereby) the
>   entire family upto the seventh generation shall be free from the fear
>   of serpents.**

[This book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=OyMJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA26&dq=skanda%20purana%20kasi%20khanda%20vasuki&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip5JWSkrnVAhWIv48KHZMbCXgQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=skanda%20purana%20kasi%20khanda%20vasuki&f=false) cites a translation of a passage from **Skanda Purana Kasi Khanda**

(I wasn't able locate the actual passage from the Purana, but this translation seems to provide the ritual in its entirety which is why I'm linking it here)

> I proceed to a translation regarding this festival: it is from the
>   portion of the Skanda Purana, termed Kási Khanda, or the Section
>   relating to Kasi or Benares;
>
> "**The fifth lunar day of Srávana is held sacred to the Nagas**; on that
>   day let ablutions be performed in the pool termed Vasuki, of sacred to
>   Vasuki the Lord of the Nagas: by observing this “ceremony the Nagas
>   are pleased, and the votaries may rest free from “ the dread of
>   Serpents.
>
> People should collect together for the purpose of amusement and for
>   worship; **the door posts should be smeared with cow dung, and figures
>   should be drawn of deadly poisonous Serpents, and offerings should be
>   made to the Nagas, of ghee, durva grass, kusa and flowers, also of
>   perfumes, garlands, and the like;** by such observance, whole families
>   reside free from dread of Serpents.
>
> The drawings of the Nagas should represent them armed with scymitars
>   and shields. The upper part of the body from the navel, should be that
>   of a human being, and the lower part that of a Serpent-hoods must be
>   extended over the heads, and entwined with any odd number of snakes;
>   all these must be of a deadly black hue, and painted either in the
>   open highway, or in the house. **This fifth day of Sravana is a day of
>   festival among the Nagas, let their images therefore be bathed in
>   milk.”**

Comment: Another excellent find.

Answer (score 4):

@Fire, for every Indian festival celebrated, there are two different directions of reasons or needs. One is of course, what you read in varaha purana. But the second is about fulfilling the day-to-day needs of human being, especially the rural culture needs. Today, we educated and service oriented people do not understand this very essential component of festival celebrations. Example is nag panchami. Snake was, is and will always be good friend of human being. What happens with the shelter places of snakes during monsoon, is the main reason to celebrate this festival. People do not dig the earth this day only to avoid physical harm to snakes who find it difficult to shelter. 
If we can take care of these species, create awareness amongst all to protect snakes that should be the good celebration. The link [how to do nag pooja](http://jaimaharashtratourism.blogspot.in/2011/08/how-to-do-simple-nag-panchami-pooja-at.html) tells the procedure to follow on this auspicious day. Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thanks you for your help but valid scriptural sources are supposed to be provided here.